# How does "mov (%ebx,%eax,4),%eax" work?

Tags: assembly, att, addressing-mode

Been working on an assembly assignment, and for the most part I understand assembly pretty well. Or well at least well enough for this assignment. But this mov statement is tripping me up. I would really appreciate if someone could just explain how this mov statement is manipulating the register values.

mov (%ebx,%eax,4),%eax

P.S. I wasnt able to find this specific type of mov statement by basic searches, so I appologize if I just missed it and am re asking questions.

Comment: This question is definitely a duplicate.  Let me look around.  Have you checked the [docs](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html)?  They explain this stuff pretty well.  You might want to translate to Intel-format assembly for easier lookup in those books, though.

Comment: I figured it would be, but I appreciate the help finding the appropriate place to look.

Comment: See also [GAS syntax addressing mode syntax](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax#Address_operand_syntax) on wikibooks, and other links in the [x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)

Comment: See also the [AT&T syntax tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info) for more details on the syntax, and links to more docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The complete memory addressing mode format in AT&T assembly is:

```
offset(base, index, width)
```

So for your case:

```
offset = 0
base = ebx
index = eax
width = 4
```

Meaning that the instruction is something like:

```
eax = *(uint32_t *)((uint8_t *)ebx + eax * 4 + 0)
```

In a C-like pseudocode.

Comment: why is `uint8_t` here?

Comment: yes, but why especially uint8? all of ebx, eax and etc... registers are 32-bit, whether the information is lost in the upper three bytes? I'm asking because i have: `leal 0x2004(%ebx), %eax` but i see: `leal 0x4(%ebx), %eax` in debugger

Comment: Because I want the `eax*4` to be in increments of bytes, not 32-bit words. Notice that it's not dereferenced as a byte.

Comment: casting to `(uintptr_t)` rather than a pointer for the math might be even clearer.