# What does mov(%edx, %ebx, 1), %al do?

Tags: assembly

I am trying to figure out a binary bomb lab, phase 5.  This is not a homework assignment but rather something I am doing on my own.

I found a similar question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900343/how-does-mov-ebx-eax-4-eax-work?rq=1) but I didn't understand the answer since there actual values were not plugged in.  I am trying to figure out what, exactly, ends up in %al, assuming that %al is the destination.  I am using gdb and the i r command showed that %ebx holds the string I entered for input, which was "device", and %edx has 0. What does this do?

Comment: I'm not assembly guru, but it looks like just assigning first byte of your `device` string to `al` register

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of MOV (%r11,%r12,1), %edx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883850/what-is-the-meaning-of-mov-r11-r12-1-edx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent Intel syntax would be `mov al, [edx+ebx*1]`

In other words, it's loading a byte from memory at the address formed by `edx + ebx*1` and placing the byte in the `al` register. Note that the `*1` (or `, 1` in AT&T syntax) is superflous; just writing `[edx+ebx]` (`(%edx, %ebx)` in AT&T syntax) would've achieved the same thing.

In your case I suppose it's reading a character from position `edx` in the string pointed to by `ebx`. It would've made more sense for the instruction to be `mov (%ebx, %edx), al` in that case, since you typically scale indices and not base addresses. But since the scaling factor is 1 here, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Actually, you cannot scale the base. In terms of Intel and AMD, **the value that you can scale is the index**. The other is base, it defines the segment register in use. Of course if base and index have same the default segment register (as `edx` and `ebx` have: `ds`) and you use a scale of 1, the difference is clear only in the encoding of the instruction. But if other was `esp` or `ebp` and the other eg. `eax`, `edx`, `ecx`, `ebx`..., the order of registers would make difference not only in the encoding, but also in the result, because of different default segment registers (`ss`/`ds`).

Comment: @nrz: Sure. But I was talking about the base address in semantic terms (i.e. the string address) rather than instruction encoding. One can write either `[base + index*scaling]` or `[index + base*scaling]` (where `base` and `index` are registers), but only one of them really makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

also look `D(a, b, c)` too.
this means `a + b * c + D` D means offset, a means base, b means index, c means scaling.
the important point in here is the scaling must be 1, 2, 4, 8 because it related to **type**

Answer (score 1):

the `()`ed instruction is for calculating the memory address.

(a, b, c) means `a + b * c`. But be aware of value of c, because it must be one of 1, 2, 4, and 8. This is because of the alignment problem.

Comment: Scaled-index addressing modes don't require alignment.  It's limited to powers of 2 because it's encoded as a 2-bit shift count in the machine code.  `index << 0..3`.